# Microsoft Azure: Find public-ip from command line of the created instance

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

I want to be able to run a script on each deployed VM in Azure that depends on the VM's public IP address.

Is there any way, from the shell, that I could curl some URL, or run the command line interface, or do anything, really, to find this information?

Comment: Do you want to get the IP of the instance you just provisioned using the azure vm create command? Or do you want to run a script on all of your currently running vms?

Comment: I want the public IP address (not what you see in ifconfig -a) from the VM itself. I need machines to know their own public IPs, even if a reboot causes the public IP to change (does Azure do this? I know AWS does)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Taken from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/95910/command-for-determining-my-public-ip)

```
curl -s checkip.dyndns.org | sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'
```

That will get you your public, outgoing IP address.

I have previously configured a small API App that has credentials to Azure Subscriptions that searches through the subscriptions for the IP Address and returns a JSON document with some pertinent configuration. (and complained a little that AWS gives you this stuff for free!)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping that I wouldn't have to do this, and that there was some way for Azure machines to figure out their own IP without knowing their own name, or any other information that needed to be accessed online. I suppose I'll just have to go with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

I keep shortcuts like this in my gists, which is pasted here:

```
azure vm show <RG_GROUP> <VM_NAME> |grep "Public IP address" | awk -F ":" '{print $3}'
```

This should give you the public IP address attached to the machine.

Note: I have not tested it with multiple public IPs attached to a single machine. This only covers the basic use case.